# [Zend]Filtering variables in a huge project

Tags: zend-framework, escaping, xss

I have huge application written in ZendFramework. Earlier everything was fine.
As for now it was redesigned and received a lot of new functionalities and options, but I have to defend this software from xss.
Variables are taken from a couple sources (webform, Webservices, api, etc.), some of them should be escaped, some not.
What do you think, what will be the best method to defend my website, without editing all (2 000 +) files and escaping all echo's ?

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework comes with a class called "Zend_Filter".  This class has a "StripTags" filter option that will strip all tags from a given string.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.set.html#zend.filter.set.striptags

If you note, even the strip tags filter isn't recommended for sanitizing input if you exclude something and it shouldn't be used to defend against XSS attacks.  It recommends using Tidy or HTMLPurifier.

http://tidy.sourceforge.net/

http://htmlpurifier.org/

I think HTML Purifier is pretty easy to use.  From their docs website:

> require_once '/path/to/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
>
> $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault(); $purifier = new
>   HTMLPurifier($config); $clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);

I hope that helps!

Cheers!